# COUNTIFS or SUMPRODUCT : Count of non-blank values in range with index criteria matching a string

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to count how many cells have a date value in a range, where the row index matches a given criteria; a string value matching a corresponding value in another column on the same row.

Basically a COUNTIF formula, where the count range is different from the search range.

I believe I almost have the answer but it's quite right:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(tblUK[Content Type]=[@[Content Type]]),tblUK[Completed]<>"")
```

Edit: The data is actually two different tables, this might clarify:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(tblUK[Content Type]=tblBurndown[@[Content Type]]),tblUK[Completed]<>"")
```

or without Table formula jargon...

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(UK!F:F="Physical",UK!E:E<>"")
```

Comment: try this =SUMPRODUCT(--(tblUK[Content Type]>1),tblUK[Completed]<>"")

Comment: Sorry that aint it, I have edited the question to add more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with an answer using COUNTIFS after all:

```
=COUNTIFS(tblUK[Completed],">0",tblUK[Content Type],[@[Content Type]])
```

However, I don't see why SUMPRODUCT won't do the job just as well, would be good to find out why it isn't working.

Edit: I think I've cracked it... just had to do a bit more reading on SUMPRODUCT. The missing element was **multiplying** the boolean array (first array) by the 2nd array.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(tblUK[Content Type]=[@[Content Type]])*(tblUK[Completed]>DATEVALUE("01/01/1900")))
```